# Advanced Filtering Excel direct/inverse proportionality

Tags: excel, excel-formula, filtering

A category has 3 features in 3 columns in an excel table, 2 fields are such that the greater the score the better the result, and in the third field the lesser the score the better the result. 
How do I combine these conditions to generate a combined ranking of the items in the category??

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a mathematical question and it rather depends on your preference. I'd do it using weighted method.

For parameters 1 and 2, weight them such that e.g. D2=A2*1; E2=B2*2. For parameter 3, weight them in negative magnitude, e.g. F2 = C2*-5. The weight is dependent on the importance of parameter.

Finally, sum up the weighted values. Sort them using Excel sort.

Sorry that I'm new and do not have the right to post picture here. So here's the link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jd7Rg.jpg